# How to get last seven record from db in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
     
$posts=head::select('DATE','fno')->limit('7')->get();
```

I used this code but it returns first 7 record  i want to return last seven inserted record

Comment: as per laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#latest-oldest you can achieve this $result::YourModel::select('DATE','fno')->latest()->take(7)->get();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
$posts=head::select('DATE','fno')->latest('DATE')->take(7)->get();
```

Comment: it returns data mismatched  dates  by using latest

Comment: Not getting you, mismatched means

Comment: If you need latest by Date so I updated answer

Comment: it returns 2021-06-11 00:00:00 this date but  Its not in database

Comment: Update your questing with DB records

Comment: And dd() your result

Comment: sorry my table has more rows i have not seen thanks

Answer (score 3):

if `Date` column is inserted date time.you can do this

```php
$posts = head::select('DATE','fno')->orderBy('DATE','desc')->limit(7)->get()
```

in your code,you don't get the last record becuase sql limit if start from above.so we order by something reverse.here we reverse `DATE`

Comment: it returns mismatched record

Comment: can you tell me which kinds of mismatched?and what is the data type of `DATE`,varchar or date?

Comment: $posts = head::select('DATE','fno')->orderBy('DATE','desc')->limit(7)->get()

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation, `oldest` order your query by date. By default, the result will be ordered by the table's `created_at` column. If you want to change the column that it reference, put the column name inside the `oldest` syntax. Like so, `...->oldest("column_name")->...`

```
$posts=head::select('DATE','fno')->oldest()->limit(7)->get();
```

Comment: it returns this date 2021-06-11 00:00:00 but this not in my table oops whats going on??

Answer (score 2):

Change the date format accordingly. It will work.

```
$posts = head::select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(DATE,'%Y-%m-%d')", 'fno')->take(7)->get();
```